# Restricting redirection to home page from the authentication page in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am making an authentication page using node.js and bootstrap. I have been able to login successfully and when I log out, my login page closes and takes me back to the home page.

when i used BACK button from the browser also, the home page is opened.
I want to force the user to login first. the user should not be able to use the BACK button of the browser to go to the home page.